# Removing a category in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm writting a small app in Meteor. I finished the code for adding a category but I don't know how to remove a category.
My code in HTML is :

```
<template name="categories">
<h2>Stored Category</h2>
<div id="categories" class="btn-group">
    {{#if new_cat}}
        <div id="category">
            <input type="text" id="add-category" value=""/>
        </div>      
    {{else}}            
        <div class="category btn btn-inverse" id="btnNewCat">&plus;</div>
    {{/if}}

    {{#if del_cat}}
        <div id="category">
            <input type="text" id="del-category" value=""/>
        </div>      
    {{else}}            
        <div class="category btn btn-inverse" id="btnDelCat">&minus;</div>
    {{/if}}

    {{#each lists}}
        <div class="category btn btn-inverse">
            {{Category}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

The button for adding a category is, obviously, btnNewCat and to delete is btnDelCat. 
Javascript code is :

```
    Template.categories.lists = function () {
    return lists.find({}, {sort: {Category: 1}});
};

Session.set('adding_category', false);
Session.set('deleting_category', false);

Template.categories.new_cat = function () {
    return Session.equals('adding_category',true);
};

Template.categories.del_cat = function(){
    return Session.equals('deleting_category',true);
};

Template.categories.events({
    'click #btnNewCat': function (e, t) {
        Session.set('adding_category', true);
        Meteor.flush();
        focusText(t.find("#add-category"));
    },
    'keyup #add-category': function (e,t){
        if (e.which === 13)
        {
            var catVal = String(e.target.value || "");
            if (catVal)
            {
                lists.insert({Category:catVal});
                Session.set('adding_category', false);
            }
        }
    },
    'focusout #add-category': function(e,t){
        Session.set('adding_category',false);
    },

    'click #btnDelCat': function (e, t) {
        Session.set('deleting_category', true);
        Meteor.flush();
        focusText(t.find("#del-category"));
    },
    'keyup #del-category': function (e,t){
        if (e.which === 13)
        {
            var catVal = String(e.target.value || "");
            if (catVal)
            {
                alert(catVal);
                lists.remove({Category:catVal});
                Session.set('deleting_category', false);
            }
        }
    },
    'focusout #del-category': function(e,t){
        Session.set('deleting_category',false);
    }
```

I try to remove using *lists.remove({Category:catVal});*. It does not work. Where I did wrong ?

Thank you,

eb_cj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only remove an item in the client by `_id`, so you need to do the following:

```
var removeCat = lists.findOne({Category:catVal});
if (removeCat) lists.remove(removeCat._id);
```

Trying this stuff in the browser console should indicate if your code works in principle; if you try to do `lists.remove({Category:catVal})`, it should give you:

> Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove documents by ID. [403]

but the code above should work.